# The modulus of a product with a large UInt64 integer is incorrect

Tags: c#

Why does the last output line return 51? First line proves that a mod b is zero. I would expect the third line to also be zero because I'm just multiplying the number by the same B.

There are no exceptions being thrown. I assume it's an overflow but why? And how to avoid this?

```
UInt64 A = 749243140505953395;
UInt64 B = 71;

Console.WriteLine((A % B) == 0);
Console.WriteLine((A*B) < UInt64.MaxValue); 
Console.WriteLine((A * B) % B);
```

Comment: i'm guessing overflow?

Comment: wrap it in a `checked` block.

Comment: `A*B` evaluates to -2143969245205963803

Comment: @Harold in fact , it is 53196262975922691045

Comment: cechode, try it with `BigInteger A = 749243140505953395;`

Comment: Many thanks @EZI.   haven't thought of System.Numeric :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is quite a nice language with very little undefined behavior.  But what you are seeing here is just that, you get a wildly incorrect value.  What is rather tragic is that this kind of failure mode is incredibly easy to avoid.  Microsoft seriously screwed up on their project templates.

But nothing you cannot fix.  Ensure the Debug configuration is selected, then use Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button > tick the "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" option.  Run your program again and you'll now get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in Example.exe
>   Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

You can leave the option turned off for the Release build, assuming you gained enough confidence in your code, overflow checking is pretty expensive.  Adds a nanosecond, give or take.  Not the kind of expense you ever worry about in the Debug build.

Answer (score 2):

The last output line returns 51 for the following reasons.

First of all, A*B results in 64-bit unsigned integer overflow. Here is why.
71 * 749243140505953395 = 53196262975922691045
This product is greater than UInt64.MaxValue, which is equal to 18446744073709551615

According to the C# language specification, in an unchecked context, overflows are ignored and any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type are discarded. So 53196262975922691045, which is hexadecimal 2 E2 3F 17 54 AA 22 DB E5, becomes E2 3F 17 54 AA 22 DB E5 (after trimming the high order bits the leading hexadecimal "2" or "10" in binary are discarded). For your reference, the maximum of the desination type 64-bit unsigned integer in hexadecimal is FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF

The hexadecimal after trimming the high-order bits ( E2 3F 17 54 AA 22 DB E5 ) converted to decimal is 16302774828503587813. The trimmed number is represented by an unsigned 64 bit integer without causing an overflow.

And finally,  16302774828503587813 % 71 = 51

On a passing note, as @EZI just noted, with really big integers you are better off using the BigInteger sructure.

Comment: many thanks for the detailed response ( will bump it ).  the BigInteger ended up being significantly slow and i ended up just splitting the big number to smaller products which seems to run much much faster in larger batches of modulus operations